# documents jumping up and down

Tags: libreoffice

my laptop is acting weird. When I open a document on LibreOffice Writer and LibreOffice spreadsheets, the documents keep jumping up and down. How can I sort it out?

I use Footswitch2 to do transcriptions, and it works well on my desktop. But somehow on my laptop it gives all kinds of icons on an LibreOffice Writer document. I thought the  Footswitch2 software might be the problem so I uninstalled it, But the icons still remain on the  documents and the documents still jump up and down.

Anybody out there who can help me?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this sometimes happens with specific documents, especially documents imported from doc word format. Perhaps try saving the file in .odt format, then close the file and reopen it. If that solves the issue, edit your file in .odt format and write it out to docx only when you need to exchange.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it's a new laptop, onto which I had Ubuntu installed, there are no documents on it, but when i open libre docs it just jumps up and down, so it's not got anything to do with importing other docs, regarding which I've never had a problem either way on my Ubuntu desk top

Comment: Has anyone perhaps used Footswitch2, software for a foot pedal with Ubuntu?